# What is the max_files in spdlog rotating files?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, c++14, spdlog

My understanding of this is that the file will be limited to the specified size. But I don't understand the `max_files = 3`, are we going to
have one or three files?

I run the example here and got one file.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "spdlog/sinks/rotating_file_sink.h"

void rotating_example()
{
    // Create a file rotating logger with 5mb size max and 3 rotated files
    auto max_size = 1048576 * 5;
    auto max_files = 3;
    auto logger = spdlog::rotating_logger_mt("some_logger_name", "logs/rotating.txt", max_size, max_files);

    logger->info("loggers can be retrieved from a global registry using the spdlog::get(logger_name)");
}

int main()
{
    rotating_example();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hope this can help you about rotated files https://www.networkworld.com/article/3218728/how-log-rotation-works-with-logrotate.html

Answer (score 1):

It is up to 3 files. Once the log file, say `mylog.txt` size reaches 5MB it gets rotated, i.e. renamed to `mylog.1txt` and a new empty one with the original name `mylog.txt` is created. Once the new one reaches 5MB the previous one is renamed to `mylog.2txt` and the current one to `mylog.1txt` and a new empty one is created again with the original name `mylog.txt`. Once the limit is reached files are no longer rotated and after reaching the limit the current file is truncated instead.

The spdlog implementation is relatively straightforward. It is very easy to analyse it. See [rotating algorithm](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/8fb112158a64afe1bd58c82c06bf6a142c9b3823/include/spdlog/sinks/rotating_file_sink-inl.h#L96) and [renaming algorithm](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/8fb112158a64afe1bd58c82c06bf6a142c9b3823/include/spdlog/sinks/rotating_file_sink-inl.h#L55)

Comment: According to the `fmt/10.1.1` documentation, if files count limit is reached, the oldest file is getting deleted.